# Unable to import a json file to my firebase database

Tags: firebase

My json file looks something like this:

```
{
"Manpower": [{
    "DESIGNATION TEXT": "Chief Engineer",
    "DISCIPLINE TEXT": "MECHANICAL",
    "LEVEL": "E5",
    "Mobile No": "123456789",
    "NAME": "John Doe"
  }]
}
```

I have checked my json file's validity from many sites and all of them saying that json file is valid yet firebase is not accepting this file saying it is not valid.

please someone help

Answer (score 0):

You need import this json file from Firebase Console.I have Imported on my own database with the following view.

[image]

Comment: Dear Vr, I am trying to upload a json file to firebase database. As you can see my json file is valid and meets all firebase conditions. Yet i am unable to upload. Please help